# Executing date utility in awk in linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, awk

I am trying to format some text from a file using awk.

The requirement is to replace the 3rd field of a colon-seperated file (:) representing epoch time with a formatted string representing the human-readable time in the follow format:
DD/MM/YYYY

Here is an example file:

```
abc:$3$wHe$JKAP1Ry.CAcEGhD0J7SGVl.AMg.0:1427135400:0:120:7:30::
rst:$6$3WWbfvblr6FF92R5/n3mLdlSkARgfRm1:1427293800:0:40:7:30::
xyz:$1$xuTkkle203F$df.ixcn/mcuFIO90lndn:1420478400:0:90:7:30::
def:$4$vid2003mDEOF$dc2.Rkdlkfdiw8/cib6:1389547200:0:120:7:30::
ab:*$5P1wHeEG$JKA2ya.ikol30.de/ldiv.230:1449771300:0:120:7:30::
xy:$1k3lc930vs.lskdie/sldiemDIIsdk193n:1429995693:0:50:7:30::
xyy:*$tkwsMt972w.Csrl5jr.23nsoijsleqJK:1429995889:0:120:7:30::
```

By copying and pasting a one of the values from the 3rd field into the a command using date I have been able to create the desired results:

```
date -d @1427135400 +"%d/%m/%Y"
23/03/2015
```

Here is the awk command that I am trying to execute in the script, I have been tweeking the script here and there in hopes to get it to work, but with no luck.
Note that $userFound has already stored a single line from the file listed above:

```
  echo $userFound | awk -F':' '{  
                                                    if ( $2 ~ /^\*/ ) {$2="L"}              \
                                                    if ($2 ~ /^[^*]/) {$2="P"}              \
                                                    cmd="date -d @"$3" +\"%d/%m/%Y\""       \
                                                    cmd | getline time                      \
                                                    close(cmd)                              \
                                            }                                               \
                                            END {                                           \
                                            print $1":"$2":"time":"$4":"$5":"$6":"$7":"$8":"$9      \
                                            }'
```

Running the current script, I get the following output:

```
awk: cmd. line:5: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: expression for `|' redirection has null string value
```

Comment: You're script doesn't have the `(FILENAME=- FNR=1)` part, please post the whole thing.

Comment: The script receives the input from the pipe, all the awk code is there. The post below (marked as answer) solved the issue. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I've posted your script with a few changes and I get what I think is the correct output.

Comment: Get rid of all the backslashes from the end of lines. Half of them aren't necessary and the other half are breaking your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `date` command like you are trying to use.

Use `awk` function: `strftime("%d/%m/%Y", $3)`.

More info [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)

Comment: Note specifically which `awk`s support that extension - follow inshsane's link.

Comment: gawk does this.  current [mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/mawk.html) does this as well.  It is not in POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to use the `date` (because you don't have GNU awk), your script works with a few changes, namely the print statement shouldn't be in the END block.

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ":"
    OFS = ":"
}
{
    if ( $2 ~ /^\*/ ) {$2="L"}      
    if ($2 ~ /^[^*]/) {$2="P"}
    cmd="date -d @" $3 " +\"%d/%m/%Y\""
    cmd | getline time
    close(cmd)
    print $1, $2, time, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9
}
```

If you put this script in a file called a.awk, then you can do

```
awk -f a.awk foo.txt
```

And if foo.txt looks like this:

```
abc:$3$wHe$JKAP1Ry.CAcEGhD0J7SGVl.AMg.0:1427135400:0:120:7:30::
rst:$6$3WWbfvblr6FF92R5/n3mLdlSkARgfRm1:1427293800:0:40:7:30::
xyz:$1$xuTkkle203F$df.ixcn/mcuFIO90lndn:1420478400:0:90:7:30::
def:$4$vid2003mDEOF$dc2.Rkdlkfdiw8/cib6:1389547200:0:120:7:30::
ab:*$5P1wHeEG$JKA2ya.ikol30.de/ldiv.230:1449771300:0:120:7:30::
xy:$1k3lc930vs.lskdie/sldiemDIIsdk193n:1429995693:0:50:7:30::
xyy:*$tkwsMt972w.Csrl5jr.23nsoijsleqJK:1429995889:0:120:7:30::
```

Then this is the output:

```
abc:P:23/03/2015:0:120:7:30::
rst:P:25/03/2015:0:40:7:30::
xyz:P:05/01/2015:0:90:7:30::
def:P:12/01/2014:0:120:7:30::
ab:P:10/12/2015:0:120:7:30::
xy:P:25/04/2015:0:50:7:30::
xyy:P:25/04/2015:0:120:7:30::
```